# Can't post value's to php file using AJAX Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having an incredibly hard time with this. I'm trying to post my value's from a form to a php file using ajax jquery. I do find the values in my console but when i execute the ajax method it doesn't post the values.

Jquery code

```
var formData = [];

function formValidate() {
 var error = false;
  $(".form .required").each(function(k, v) {
   $(v).removeClass("error");
   if ($(v).attr("type") === "radio" && $(v).prop("checked")) {
     formData[$(v).attr("id")] = $(v).val();
   } else if ($(v).val() === "") {
     $(v).addClass("error");
     //$(v).prop("placeholder”,”Required.”);
     error = true;
   } else {
     formData[$(v).attr("id")] = $(v).val();
   }
  });
    console.log(formData); //all data is successful shown 
    return error;
 }

// send function
function formSend() {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "include/mail.php",
  data: formData,
  dataType: "html",
  encode: true,
  success: function(response) {
     alert(response);

  },
  error: function() {
     $("form").hide();
  }
 });
 event.preventDefault();

}
```

Html code

```
<form action="" id="form-3">
 <div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control required" name="naam" placeholder="Naam" id="naam">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="telnr" placeholder="Telefoon" id="telnr">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control required" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="email">
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

I do find the value's if i console.log(formData) so why won't it post it?

**EDIT:**

here you can see the images of the console log

[image: The values need to be send to mail.php]

When the request is made. 
The values need to be send to mail.php

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And here you can see that formData does display if i use console.log

Comment: also look into using the serialize function from jquery, makes things much easier: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: What is the v in `$(v)` referring to? `formData[$(v).attr("id")] = $(v).val();` You are trying to set associative array using `[]` ?

Comment: Hi, where the "formSend()" function is called? I don't see any send.
And can you make a capture of the request (in chrome, dev tools => network) and show us?

Comment: formSend() is called in a simple .click() function i doubt the problem is there. , my question is updated for the console log images. @Vincent

Comment: $(v) is a input element @frz3993

Comment: How you are calling `formSend()` & `formValidate()`?

Comment: check the full jquery code here https://jsfiddle.net/e23wy5gk/1/ @itzmukeshy7

Comment: url seems wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is `formData` is a **JSONArray** - but in the ajax call you need to provide a **JSONObject**. So initiate `formData` as **JSONObject** in the validation function and then push the key values in it.

Rewrite the `formData` initiation like:

```
var formData = {};
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass form data using [serilize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) rather than individual field value. Try below code:

**jQuery Code:**

```
var formData = $("form").serialize();
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "YOUR PHP FILE PATH",
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
        //do stuff progressing
    },
    success: function (resp) {
       //do stuff after post
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert('error: ' + JSON . stringify(e));
    }
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST); //it will print array with all form input field
?>
```

**Note:** Set Form `action="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: error: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"php file found<b>/var/www/vhosts/huisinkoper.nl/httpdocs/include/mail.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: naam in <b>/var/www/vhosts/huisinkoper.nl/httpdocs/include/mail.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: telnr in <b>/var/www/vhosts/huisinkoper.nl/httpdocs/include/mail.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in <b>/var/www/vhosts/huisinkoper.nl/httpdocs/include/mail.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: can you please give the result of `console.log(formData)`?

Comment: I did in my question, the seconde picture is result of console.log(formData) @HimelNagRana

Comment: @Peterrosevelt sorry I missed it. Okay the problem is `formData` is a **JSONArray** - but in the `ajax` call you need to provide a **JSONObject**. So initiate `formData` as **JSONObject** in the validation function and then push the key values in it. Then it will work. Thanks.

Comment: @Peterrosevelt, you got undefined index errors on mail.php. Try fixing them first